# ¿Por qué no funciona mi bucle for? cuando hago cada paso individualmente SI obtengo los resultados que busco

Tags: r, bucle-for

Saludos querida comunidad
Estoy trabajando con una lista a la que he nombrado **test1**. Cada elemento de dicha lista es un data frame con la siguiente estrucutura

```
> str(test1[[1]])
'data.frame':   31861 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ codigo_estacion: num  86011 86011 86011 86011 86011 ...
 $ fecha_hora     : chr  "2019-02-28 16:00:00" "2019-02-28 16:10:00" "2019-02-28 16:20:00" "2019-02-28 16:30:00" ...
 $ precipitacion  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

No todos los dataframes de la lista tienen la misma cantidad de filas, pero todos ellos si tienen exactamente los mismos campos y mismo tipo de datos en cada uno de ellos.
Mi propósito es crear un nuevo vector que contenga el codigo de estación de cada dataframe de la lista.

```
nomb <- character(0)

for(i in length(test1)) {
  nomb[i] = test1[[i]][1,1]
}
```

Pero por algún motivo, que claramente estoy pasando por alto, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
> nomb
 [1] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[17] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[33] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[49] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[65] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "86299"
```

Como pueden ver solamente el último elemento del vector que he creado guarda el codigo de estación. Es algo que ya había hecho en el pasado con otros datos y funcionaba perfectamente bien.

Luego por ejemplo si pruebo lo siguiente:

```
> nomb[1] = test1[[1]][1, 1]
> nomb[3] = test1[[3]][1, 1]
> nomb
 [1] "86011" NA      "86027" NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[17] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[33] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[49] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
[65] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "86299"
```

Logro agregar el codigo de estacion a los elementos uno y dos del vector **nomb**, es decir al hacer el proceso individualmente si funciona. Lo que me dice que mi error esta al escribir el ciclo for, pero no estoy pudiendo descifrarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar una funcional en lugar de un bucle. En este caso `sapply()` de Rbase funcionaría.

```
list(data.frame(a = 1),
     data.frame(a = 2)) -> foo

sapply(foo, `[[`, c(1,1))
```

Produce un vector numérico `1 2`.

En R se pueden usar bucles, pero las funcionales son casi siempre mejor alternativa. Te ahorras el trabajo de armar explícitamente el iterador, organizar la salida del output y sincronizar el índice.

En este caso uso `sapply()`, que pasa una función a cada elemento de la lista `foo` y simplifica el output. Simplifica: si es una lista lo pasa a un objeto más simple, en este caso un vector.

La función que uso es `[[`, con los argumentos `c(1, 1)`. Se ve muy raro, pero no es más que el tradicional operador de subset de R. Es el equivalente sintáctico de `df[[1, 1]]`.

Tomando como ejemplo una lista:

```
`[[`(foo, 2)
```

es equivalente a

```
foo[[2]]
```

Casi todos los bucles en R se puede reemplazar por funcionales: `sapply()` si quieres que un vector o matriz como output, `lapply()` si quieres una lista, etc.
Además puedes aprovechar muy bien las funciones anónimas. No es necesario definir antes la función que va a pasar `sapply()`, la defines en la misma llamada.

Por si fuera poco si estás pasando una función muy compleja que demora mucho tiempo son súper fáciles de paralelizar. En UNIX es cuestión de cambiar `lapply()` por `mclapply()` y cada elemento de la lista se evaluará en un núcleo distinto del procesador. Todo ventaja.

Estas características de programación funcional son de lo mejor que tiene R. Da un poco de trabajo naturalizar como funcionan, pero vale la pena. A futuro te ahorras mucho tiempo programando bucles y organizándoles el output.

Ahora, si después de este speech de ventas sigues prefiriendo los bucles...

El problema del que programaste es que está iterando sobre un solo valor `length(test1)`. Si quieres iterar sobre toda la secuencia deberías usar:

```
nomb <- character(0)

for(i in 1:length(test1)) {
  nomb[i] = test1[[i]][1,1]
}
```

Donde se crea la secuencia `1:length(test1)`